# Dúvida ao fazer um ranking utilizando django!

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Estou fazendo um site de um jogo utilizando django e quero fazer um ranking baseado na pontuação de todos os usuários! Por enquanto está assim:

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    perfis = Perfil.objects.all().order_by('-pontuacao_ultima')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'perfis' : perfis})
```

**index.html**:

```
{% for perfis in perfis %}
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{{ perfis.nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ perfis.pontuacao_ultima }} pontos</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

No caso ele já está ordenando, porém eu estou com dúvida no que fazer para o número da posição variar de acordo com a posição real do player(primeiro, segundo, etc). Por enquanto ele está mostrando apenas o 1 (coloquei manualmente no html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a tag `forloop.counter`:

```
{% for perfil in perfis %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ perfil.nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ perfil.pontuacao_ultima }} pontos</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Existem outras tags com diferentes funções, como começar contando a partir de zero `forloop.counter0`, verificar se é o primeiro laço do loop `{% if forloop.first %}`, etc.

Mais detalhes podem ser vistas na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, acredito que um "enumerate" possa te ajudar, e, segundo a documentação do Django, você teria um disponível através da variável `{{ forloop.counter }}` dentro seu bloco `for`, isso porquê você quer um ranking inciando do 1, se não, se quisesse o real Index do objeto dentro da lista, poderia usar o {{ forloop.counter0 }}.

Referências:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013367/how-to-run-this-code-in-django-template

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Espero ter ajudado!